# Error launching Safari with PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine

I've installed PlayOnLinux with the following commands:

```
wget -q -O- http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update

# useful dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y curl p7zip-full

# install playonlinux

sudo apt-get install -y playonlinux
```

and then I've installed Safari from inside PlayOnLinux. It is correctly installed, but when I try to launch it I get the next errors:

```
[01/23/14 12:15:35] - Running wine-1.4.1 Safari.exe (Working directory : /home/manolo/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Safari/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Safari)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No exApplication tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Unknown error (127).
[01/23/14 12:15:47] - Running wine-1.4.1 Safari.exe (Working directory : /home/manolo/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Safari/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Safari)
err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winex11.drv": libSM.so.6: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winex11.drv": libSM.so.6: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winemp3.acm": libmpg123.so.0: clase ELF errónea: ELFCLASS64
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:shell:SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID L"Apple.Safari": stub
fixme:advapi:GetCurrentHwProfileA (0x32f9ec) semi-stub
fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x32fb48
fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
fixme:service:EnumServicesStatusW resume handle not supported
fixme:service:EnumServicesStatusW resume handle not supported
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No exApplication tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Unknown error (127).
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:msg:pack_message msg 14 (WM_ERASEBKGND) not supported yet
err:ole:RegisterDragDrop invalid hwnd (nil)
err:ole:RegisterDragDrop invalid hwnd (nil)
err:ole:RegisterDragDrop invalid hwnd (nil)
err:ole:RegisterDragDrop invalid hwnd (nil)
err:ole:RegisterDragDrop invalid hwnd (nil)
```

Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Did you enable multi-arch support? You can check this with `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: @byrmgcl - `i386` is the only output. How can enable multi-arch support?

Comment: With this command `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64` after that run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @byrmgcl - Thanks, but same error...

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get -f install` maybe you can fix dependendent packages...

Comment: @byrmgcl - No way. I'm getting the same error and the same output on `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12629/discussion-between-manolo-salsas-and-byrmgcl)

Comment: @byrmgcl - Won't you post your answer?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @byrmgcl - Yes. I told you in the chat. Just installing from the OS repo.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must enable multi-arch support which architecture if you can't use:

> `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64`

or

> `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Because it might use wine64 or wine:i386 
Second, run:

> `sudo apt-get update`

and

> `sudo apt-get -f install`

If it hasn't been fixed dependencies then you can manually install wine64 or wine:i386 :

> `sudo apt-get install wine64`

or

> `sudo apt-get install wine:i386`

The issue still hasn't fixed then remove playonlinux and remove repository playonlinux. 
After install playonlinux from your distribution repositories then all dependencies will install.

Answer (score 0):

Update `playonlinux` from [this website](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html).

You might have upgraded your Ubuntu to the latest version and have `playonlinux` installed in the old version.